# Pandas: How to merge two columns with a second DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe `df` containing new `IDs` while in `dfOld` I have the corresponce between old and new `IDs`

```
df
   ID1new ID2new
0  5       3
1  4       2
2  3       7


dfOld

   IDold IDnew
0  33       0
1  78       1
2  65       2
3  12       3
4  24       4
5  89       5
6  77       6
7  16       7
8  69       8
```

I want to add two columns to `df` containing the old `IDs` for `ID1new` and `ID2new`, so

```
df1
   ID1new ID2new   ID1old   ID2old
0  5       3         89       12
1  4       2         24       65
2  3       7         12       16
```

I am brutally doing a loop like this:

```
df1 = df
df1['ID1old']=0
df1['ID2old']=0
for i in net.index:
    tmp  = dfOld[dfOld.IDnew == df.ID1new[i]]
    tmp0 = dfOld[dfOld.IDnew == df.ID2new[i]]
    net.ID1old[i] = tmp.IDold[tmp.index[0]]
    net.ID1old[i] = tmp0.IDold[tmp0.index[0]]
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` `d` or `Series` `s`:

```
d = dfOld.set_index('IDnew')['IDold'].to_dict()
print (d)
{0: 33, 1: 78, 2: 65, 3: 12, 4: 24, 5: 89, 6: 77, 7: 16, 8: 69}

#s = dfOld.set_index('IDnew')['IDold']

df['ID1old'] = df.ID1new.map(d)
df['ID2old'] = df.ID2new.map(d)
print (df)
   ID1new  ID2new  ID1old  ID2old
0       5       3      89      12
1       4       2      24      65
2       3       7      12      16
```